# Flying on the 2nd floor of the airplane

Tags: air-travel, airlines, paris, seating, san-francisco

So I will go to the check-in in an hour. My seat is on the 2nd floor of a 380 of Air France, is there I need to know? Or is just the same damn thing as flying on the 1st floor?

---

PS - For some reason, I am exited, since this will be my 1st time! :D

Comment: Make sure you can carry all your carry-on stuff up a flight of stairs.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan good point, but I have my Machamp with me! :)

Comment: I find the atmosphere more relaxed, it is a smaller cabin and not as noise typically. It feels like being with a large family, much nicer. But that's just me.

Comment: @Aganju that was the motivation for me as well, the small cabin, so it's not just you! ;)

Comment: In many cases, the jetway will slope up/down so you simply enter on the correct deck without stairs. In any event, there will be signs and/or airline staff to guide you to the right place when you board.

Comment: Yeah @ZachLipton, I am not worried about that, farewell!!! :)

Comment: Have a good trip!

Comment: @gsamaras Did you have to get a separate ticket for your Machamp, or do you merely put him back into your Poké Ball after taking your seat?

Comment: @Fiksdal that's a super great comment for the 1st one I read back in Greece! In the Pokeball ofc!! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How fun for you.

Every airline and airport has slightly different signage so pay attention.

Air France flys only one configuration of the A380 with Rows 1-51 on the lower deck and 60-93 on the upper deck.

Also, all First Class seats are on the lower deck and all Business and Premium Economy are on the upper deck so if you're in one of those cabins, that's where to go.

Other than there being two, there's nothing really special about either one.  They both get there at the same time :).

Comment: Are you sure? I will be further than the center of the earth than the people on the 1st floor, which will affect the relative spin, thus I am not sure about the time of arrival! haha thank you John!

Comment: @gsamaras You'd have to replace all the passengers with scientific instruments to detect any such difference in time. Which would, I think, defeat the purpose of the trip. :)

Comment: Do I have time for such a replacement? I doubt it! :)) Time to check in, ciao ciao!

Comment: Any explanation for the downvotes?

Comment: Without feedback, downvote totally unwarrented.

Comment: @Johns-305 agreed, so I gave you an +1; perhaps some unknown didn't realize that a bit of fun was being had with fellow traveler gsamaras